# Как установить цвет и шрифт тайтла кнопки в navBar?

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios10, uinavigationbar

Каким образом можно поменять цвет (должен отличаться от цвета заголовка экрана в навигационной панели) надписи на кнопке в навигационной панели?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        title = "title of screen"

        //

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonIconGreen"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("buttonTitle", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

//        buttonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium),
//                                      NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .normal)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("button tapped")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
```

Просто меняем цвет

Comment: упс, а у меня почему-то этот очевидный вариант в первый раз не сработал. где-то ошибся, видимо. Спасибо )